# How to show preview of the image clicked?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

using custom camera how can we show the preview of the fullsize  image after the image is being clicked from camera clicked and in preview if we can show whether to accept the image or discard the image before saving it to SD card.(Hint: As used in watsapp)

Comment: I would suggest to do following programmatically, Capture image-> create temp directory in sd card(like whtsapp) save it their. Make sure you compress it. Retrieve the image from that path and display it. You can google it on stack overflow for each step i mentioned. You might also come across OOM exceptions if bitmaps are not handled properly.

Comment: Please can you show me any example of it through code ??

Comment: I will guide you towards the solution. Go through below link. Camera api is nicely explained.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: Sorry but it doesnot solve my purpose... As i have mentioned above i want to show preview of the fullsize image with saving and delete button for the  users choice and then save it in sd card

Answer (score 0):

You will get image in byte[], you can convert this byte[] into bitmap and can show it in ImageView

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(yourbytearray, 0, yourbytearray.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete code according to your requirement is given below. Just follow this.Here uImage is Bitmap and imageView is the imageview where your image will be displayed.

```
private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddownRecipeFromHome.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }


    private Uri getTempUri() {
        return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
    }
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {

                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    uImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(uImage);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        uImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
               uImage = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.e("path of imag", ""+picturePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(uImage);
            }
         else if (requestCode == 3) {
                try {
                    Log.e("testing", "return data is  " + data.getData());

                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/" + TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
                    System.out.println("path " + filePath);
                    uImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    uImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bao);
                    ba = bao.toByteArray();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(uImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
}


   private File getTempFile() {

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            return file;
        } else {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the "ba" ???